# Trouble mapping multiple subfolders to destinations in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We've switched servers and for whatever reason, our htaccess file isn't behaving the same way as it was on the other. I'm going to be the first to admit that I'm not an htaccess superuser, and I have no doubt the answer's probably looking me in the face, but literally an entire Saturday of searches hasn't fixed this. I have this filesystem:

*When the domain is* **/category/subcategory/product/**

*It should rewrite to* **/category/product-details.php?p=product&s=subcategory**

*When the domain is*  **/category/subcategory/**

*It should rewrite to* **/category-product-list.php?slug=subcategory**

This seems simple enough, here's the same code we had been using for years. Note, we've commented out the first two RewriteRules regarding slashes and there was no change in behavior.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
# if folder does not end with a slash redirect to with slash
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /$1/ [L,NC,R=301]
#if it does not end with a slash e.g. rock-jewelry/some-piece, add the slash
RewriteRule ^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+/[-a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /$1/ [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ category/product-details.php?p=$2s=$1   [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ category-product-list.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```

*When the domain is* **/category/subcategory/product/**

*It rewrites to* **/category-product-list.php?slug=product-details.php&p=product&s=subcategory**

*When the domain is*  **/category/subcategory/**

*It **correctly** rewrites to* **/category-product-list.php?slug=subcategory**

/category/ is an actual folder, and the only thing in it is product-details.php, there is no index.php file, the htaccess is supposed to rewrite to category-product-list if they're trying to access the index.

If we remove the category-product-list.php rule, the product-details.php rule DOES work. But isn't the L directive supposed to stop at the first rule? Why is the second still running? And how can I write a better way to accomplish this goal? Thank you very much, I'm pretty beat down on this problem at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you to understand the why of this loop... But it's like that.

You can add that before the last RewriteRule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Or if you don't use dot in subcategory, you can use final RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^category/([^./]+)/?$ category-product-list.php?slug=$1 [L,QSA]
```